# Lodash - How can I get all the object from a collection match an array of strings criteria

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to the object from a collection using an array for the criteria

something like this:

```
let collection = [
{id: '1', text: 'Hello'}, 
{id: '2', text: 'Bye'},
{id: '3', text: 'See you'},
];

const criteria = ['1', '2'];
```

and the result needs to be:

```
let newArray = [
{id: '1', text: 'Hello'}, 
{id: '2', text: 'Bye'}
];
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Lodash?

Comment: `let newArray = collection.filter(o => criteria.includes(o.id));`

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: @NinaScholz returns all the objects with the an id that matches the array's values

Comment: @Tushar liked your answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need lodash for that

```js
let collection = [
{id: '1', text: 'Hello'}, 
{id: '2', text: 'Bye'},
{id: '3', text: 'See you'},
];

const criteria = ['1', '2'];

const filtered = collection.filter((obj) => {
 return criteria.indexOf(obj.id) >= 0;
});
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Lodash you can do the following, however as the answer above states it's not necessary in this case!

```
let collection = [
{id: '1', text: 'Hello'}, 
{id: '2', text: 'Bye'},
{id: '3', text: 'See you'},
];

const criteria = ['1', '2'];

var result = _.filter(collection, function(item) {
        return _.indexOf(criteria, item.id) >= 0;
});
```